How to load sapui5 xml fragment in custom library that gets loaded from another app?
We have a custom library for controlls that we use across different sapui5 apps.
For js controls this works fine but now im trying to get it work with a xml fragment.
The library is deployed like an app and contains js files that extends sap/ui/base/Object and works fine.
We call it from other apps via
sap.ui.loader.config({
    paths: {
        'zfiorilibrary': sLibraryPath
    }
});

then we can access it from controller of the app by loading it as you load any other objects from sapui5 declaring it at the top in sap.ui.define()
now i tried the same with an xml file that is in the library and it wont load and gives me cors error in console.
this._oAttachmentsMangerDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("library-AttachmentsManager", "zfiorilibrary.fragments.AttachmentsManager", this);
jquery-dbg.js:9325 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://ourserver/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/zfiorilibrary/fragments/AttachmentsManager.fragment.xml' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
when i click the url the xml loads fine
we never have cors errors when loading the js files.
What can i do to load xml files from the library?
We are using sapui5 version 1.71.x (always the newest 1.71 available)

Is there really a request to that XML file in the Network trace? If so, is the status code 404?

On the other hand, if the fragment is part of the library, it should be included in the library bundle library-preload.js which would allow bypassing a separate request to the XML content.

Javascript files are loaded through <script> elements which make no-cors requests. They can be loaded from any origin.
By contrast, XML files cannot be loaded through an HTML element (there is no <xml>) but only through an XMLHttpRequest (or an equivalent fetch). These make cors requests. If your cross-origin server does not provide the necessary CORS headers, the browser will issue the error message that you observed.
See this documentation about setting CORS headers with your server.
